# Mathematics proof question & answer

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:

**Every** number that is being **presumed** by **0** is **1** (number$^ 0$). ***Prove it.***

Answer:

**$x^0 = x^{n-n} = x^n / x^n = 1$**

Why is that? and what does that answer really means?
And why are there proofs in mathematics classes?

Comment: As far as I remember, x^0 = 1 whatever could be x.

Comment: moreover this proof is not very good, because it does not work for x=0.

Comment: Has the question been translated from some other language?  I've not seen 'presumed' for 'exponentiated' before!
As others have commented, this proof isn't, because it doesn't work when x is 0 and yet the questions asks for a proof for _every_ number.
As for why there are proofs in mathematics classes - that's rather a soft-question I think, and the short (unhelpful) answer is that it is because there are proofs in mathematics.  A slightly better answer might be that a mathematical proof is a rigorous demonstration of why a statement is true, which is what maths is about.

Comment: @dkuper But x can be 0 too? x^(n-n) = x^0, 0^0 = 1

Comment: yes but your proof when you divide by $x^n$ is not valid if $x=0$

Comment: Why are there proofs? Because mathematics breeds thinkers, not followers. Mathematics is for you to learn on your own, classes just give you the tools to do so later. How can you verify that what someone tells you is correct if you can't sit down and prove it?

Answer (score 0):

Exponentiation is a repeated multiplication, just like multiplication itself is a repeated addition. So $a^{b+c}=a^b\cdot a^c$ for the same reason that $a(b+c)=ab+ac$ . Likewise, $a^{b-c}=a^b/a^c$ for the same reason that $a(b-c)=ab-ac$. For $b=c$ we have $a\cdot0=0$ and $a^0=1$, with the mention that $0^0$ is [undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form) (because on one hand $0$ to any power tends to be $0$, while on the other hand anything to the power $0$ tends to be $1$).

$$a(b+c)=\underbrace{a+a+a+\ldots+a}_{b+c}=\underbrace{a+a+a+\ldots+a}_b+\underbrace{a+a+a+\ldots+a}_c=ab+ac$$

$$a^{b+c}=\underbrace{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot\ldots\cdot a}_{b+c}=\underbrace{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot\ldots\cdot a}_b\cdot\underbrace{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot\ldots\cdot a}_c=a^b\cdot a^c$$

Similarly, $$a^{b-c}=\underbrace{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot\ldots\cdot a}_{b-c}=\underbrace{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot\ldots\cdot a}_{b-c}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{a^c}{a^c}}_1=\underbrace{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot\ldots\cdot a}_{b-c}\cdot\frac{\overbrace{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot\ldots\cdot a}^c}{\underbrace{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot\ldots\cdot a}_c}=$$

$$=\frac{\overbrace{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot\ldots\cdot a}^{b-c}\cdot\overbrace{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot\ldots\cdot a}^c}{\underbrace{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot\ldots\cdot a}_c}=\frac{\overbrace{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot\ldots\cdot a}^{b-c+c}}{\underbrace{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot\ldots\cdot a}_c}=\frac{\overbrace{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot\ldots\cdot a}^{b}}{\underbrace{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot\ldots\cdot a}_c}=\frac{a^b}{a^c}$$

Obviously, for $b=c$ we have $a^0=1$. Why $1$ and not $0$ ? Because the [empty product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) has to be $1$, otherwise, if it were $0$, then all other products would be $0$ as well, since $0$ times anything is always $0,$ correct ? Think about it: Don't computer programmers always initialize their products with $1,$ and their sums with $0$ ? Isn't this logical, given the fact that $0$ is the [neutral element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) when it comes to addition, and $1$ the [identity element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) when it comes to multiplication ?